# Reading from TcpStream results in empty buffer

Tags: tcp, rust, tcpclient

I want to read data from a TCP stream but it results in an empty `Vec`:

```
extern crate net2;

use net2::TcpBuilder;
use std::io::Read;
use std::io::Write;
use std::io::BufReader;

let tcp = TcpBuilder::new_v4().unwrap();
let mut stream = tcp.connect("127.0.0.1:3306").unwrap();
let mut buf = Vec::with_capacity(1024);
stream.read(&mut buf);    
println!("{:?}", buf); // prints []
```

When I use `stream.read_to_end` the buffer is filled but this takes way too long.

In Python I can do something like

```py
import socket 

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 3306
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
#s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close() 
print "received data:", data
```

How can I achieve this in Rust?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The two methods you tried don't work for different reasons:

- [`read()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#tymethod.read): "does not provide any guarantees about whether it blocks waiting for data". In general, `read()` is unreliable from a users perspective and should only be used as a building block for higher level functions, like `read_to_end()`.

  But maybe more importantly, you have a bug in your code: you create your vector via `with_capacity()` which reserves memory internally, but doesn't change the length of the vector. It is still empty! When you now slice it like `&buf`, you pass an empty slice to `read()`, thus `read()` cannot read any actual data. To fix that, the elements of your vector need to be initialized: `let mut buf = vec![0; 1024]` or something like that.
- [`read_to_end()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_end): calls `read()` repeatedly until EOF is encountered. This doesn't really make sense in most TCP stream situations.

So what should you use instead? In your Python code you read a specific number of bytes into a buffer. You can do that in Rust, too: [`read_exact()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_exact). It works like this:

```
const BUFFER_SIZE: usize = 1024;

let mut stream = ...;
let mut buf = [0; BUFFER_SIZE];
stream.read_exact(&mut buf);

println!("{:?}", buf);
```

You could also use [`take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.take). That way you can use `read_to_end()`:

```
const BUFFER_SIZE: usize = 1024;

let mut stream = ...;
let mut buf = Vec::with_capacity(BUFFER_SIZE);
stream.take(BUFFER_SIZE).read_to_end(&mut buf);

println!("{:?}", buf);
```

If you want to use the stream multiple times, you probably want to use [`by_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.by_ref) before calling `take()`.

The two code snippets are not equivalent though! Please read the documentation for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer at first. 
The problem I have - is the same as with the read_to_end.
It really takes up to 3 seconds to fill the buffer, where as the python script runs in a matter of milliseconds.
Since rust is a fast language I believe I miss something

Comment: @xhallix Strange. In that case, you have to add more information to your question. Your `TcpBuilder` is not from the standard library, so where is it from?

Comment: It is from https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/net2-rs.
But I have the same issue with the standard TcpStream. 
The tcpBuilder actually gives me the `std::net::TcpStream` 
btw. if you'd like we can continue this chat on `gitter`or else where - to prevent spamming this thread